# Chained ListEditors

Tags: gwt, gxt, gwt-editors

I have multiple entities with a one-to-many relations, such as:

```
A { List<B> b; }

B { List<C> c; }

C { some fields }
```

I'm trying to edit these entities by the editors

```
AEditor extends Editor {
 BListEditor b...
}

BListEditor implements IsEditor<ListEditor<BProxy, BListEditor.BItemEditor>>{
  BItemEditor implements Editor<BProxy>{
    CListEditor c...
  }
}

CListEditor implements IsEditor<ListEditor<CProxy, CListEditor.CItemEditor>>{
  CItemEditor implements Editor<CProxy>{}
}
```

In the UI it looks like:

```
A - Container with fields and list of items B(list of grids)
B - Container with combobox and grid - C
C - editable grid
```

So when I try to edit an already saved data it works fine.
But if I dynamically create B and C, then while saving list B.c == null

**Why RF doesn't send list of CListEditor?**

Comment: Could you first make changes to your code to determine whether it's an editor or RF issue? (i.e. is the B.c correctly populated after the `flush`? or alternatively does the bug still happen if you manually create the B and C after the `flush`, outside of the editor framework?)

Comment: They are correctly created and stored in the chain of editors in ListEditorWrapper.

Comment: But after saving a AbstractRequestContext.state.editedProxies contains BProxy.c == null, "CProxy" sent separately without the context BProxy.

Comment: And if edit an already saved data (created by junit) it works fine.

Comment: So, did you determine whether the bug is in editors or RF? It should be easy, there's a call to `flush()` in between.

Comment: Results: http://pastebin.com/En8Ughnj

Comment: Is obtained that the object B was added to the object A, and object C still remains in the array editedProxies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/caq5cDQz2r0/di2igppMXAYJ)

Need to initialize the the collections in the created proxy.